# import { pipe } from "lodash/fp" gives 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT' error

Tags: javascript, node.js, lodash

I was trying to import `pipe` from `lodash/fp`

```js
import { pipe } from "lodash/fp";
```

But getting following errors

```
Error [ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT]: Directory import '/home/user/Codes/redux-tut/node_modules/lodash/fp' is not supported resolving ES modules imported from /home/user/Videos/Codes/redux-tut/src/index.js
Did you mean to import lodash/fp.js?
    at finalizeResolution (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:267:17)
    at moduleResolve (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:668:10)
    at Loader.defaultResolve [as _resolve] (internal/modules/esm/resolve.js:758:11)
    at Loader.resolve (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:100:40)
    at Loader.getModuleJob (internal/modules/esm/loader.js:246:28)
    at ModuleWrap.<anonymous> (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:47:40)
    at link (internal/modules/esm/module_job.js:46:36) {
  code: 'ERR_UNSUPPORTED_DIR_IMPORT',
  url: 'file:///home/user/Videos/Codes/redux-tut/node_modules/lodash/fp'
}
```

My `package.json` file is

```json
{
  "name": "redux-tut",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "index.js",
  "type": "module",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "start": "node src/index.js"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "lodash": "^4.17.20"
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This solved it for me:

```
import pipe from "lodash/fp/pipe.js";
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the [help center](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer).